# Flutter app don't reach server on android

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I develop a full stack application. I use flutter as frontend and nodejs + express js as backend.

I built and released ios version to testflight and everywthing worksfine.

But when I install apk on android physical devise(galaxy j7 and galaxy s20) something went wrong. When I try to retrive some data through application(for example user data), I get nothing.

I use hosting and there is PM2 installed so I can see console.log of my backend and there is nothing too. It just seems that application don't address server.

Can anybody tell me where could be mistake?

I also check android emulator and there everything was ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you check if you have **Internet permission** in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file for main : android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml ?

If not you can add it like this

```xml
<manifest>
  // [...]
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: No. Not like that. Outside application tag please.

Comment: And explain why it would work on emulator without.

Comment: My bad, I edited. Maybe did you try in debug mode on emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and the problem was I wasn't setting the correct config in my build.gradle file. Make sure you have below in andriod/app/build.gradle:

```
android{
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'upload-alias'
            keyPassword 'Pass123'
            storeFile file('/Users/jwoodruff/upload-keystore.jks')
            storePassword 'Pass123'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

Ensure you replace the values in the release signingConfig with your own necessary values as well.